# Does Alibaba Cloud support Text Transcribe?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I currently use Amazon Transcribe to get sentiment analytics on text chat. I'm interested to switch over to Alibaba Cloud and want to know if the platform provides Sentiment Analytics feature similar to Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been testing some of the AI services from AliCloud like Machine Translation and Speech Synthesis. But I don't see service for sentiment analytics available out of the box. However new services keep getting added and I am sure it's in the product road map.