# Alibaba Cloud support Text Transcribe or not?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I currently use Amazon Transcribe to get sentiment analytics on text chat. I'm interested to switch over to Alibaba Cloud and want to know if the platform provides Sentiment Analytics feature similar to Amazon AWS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218957/

Answer (score 1):

I am glad to let you know. Now Alibaba cloud had Intelligent Speech Interaction function to support what you need!

Real-time Speech Recognition
Converts audio streams into text in real time. Intelligent segmentation is used to identify when sentences start and end. Real-time Speech Recognition is ideal for scenarios with high requirements for real-time response, such as real-time transcription for live videos, meetings, and court trials.

Recording File Recognition
Converts audio from files uploaded by users into text within 24 hours. Applicable to scenarios that are not time-sensitive, such as call center quality assurance, transcription of court trials from recordings, summarization of meeting minutes, and medical record filing.